# D3.js visualization from circles to triangles

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition, bubble-chart

Does anybody know how I might change the circles in this graph http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/ to be triangles and still dynamically grow and shrink?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to create triangles; one way to do this without doing any geometry yourself is to use [d3.svg.symbol](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-symbol) with the type "triangle-up". Like so:

- http://bl.ocks.org/3244058

Answer (score 0):

I think that the code is almost the same, but instead of drawing circles, you need to compute the vertices of a polygon with three edges. Is important that the area of your triangle to be proportional to the value that it represents. Take a look to the polygon documentation https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes